# Morse code to English?

Tags: java, string, split, morse-code

I'm trying to write something that translates English to Morse code and vice-versa. I got the English to Morse running fine, but I'm having a hard time converting it the other way. I'm meant to use `|` as the space between words, so `- --- | -... .` means "to be". Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the section of my code that's in `case:1`?

```
public class Project {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] morse = { ".- ", "-... ", "-.-. ", "-.. ", ". ", "..-. ", "--. ", ".... ", ".. ",

        ".--- ", "-.- ", ".-.. ", "-- ", "-. ", "--- ", ".--. ", "--.- ", ".-. ", "... ", "- ", "..- ",

        "...- ", ".-- ", "-..- ", "-.-- ", "--.. ", "|" };
        String[] alphabet = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", " " };

        int a;
        a = Input.getInt("Enter 1 for Morse to English or enter 2 for English to Morse.");

        switch (a)
        {
        case 2:
        {
            String toMorse = new String();
            toMorse = Input.getString("Enter a sentence.");
            toMorse = toMorse.toUpperCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < toMorse.length(); i++)
            {
                char x = toMorse.charAt(i);
                if (x == ' ') System.out.print(" | ");
                else System.out.print(morse[x - 'A']);
            }

            break;
        }

        case 1:
        {
            String toEnglish = new String();
            toEnglish = Input.getString("Enter your Morse code.");

            String[] parts = toEnglish.split("|");
            for (int x = 0; x < parts.length; x++)
            {
                if (parts.equals(morse[x])) System.out.println(alphabet[x]);
            }

            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Response");
        }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you tell which is the problem that you have found? Wrong output (which one, and which output?). Exceptions?

Comment: I'm just not getting any output when I try to enter Morse and have it translate to english.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

- [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) uses a regex command, and `|` is a special operator in regex. Instead of `|`, you want `\\|`.

  Change

  `String[] parts = toEnglish.split("|");`

  to

  `String[] parts = toEnglish.split("\\|");`
- When you do:

  `if (parts.equals(morse[x]))` then you're comparing a *reference* to a String, which is not what you  want to do..

  You probably want to do:

  `if (parts[x].equals(morse[x]))`

  Now, `parts[x]` contains a String. I recommend you to read the documentation of [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thank you for that, but it's still definitely not working. Anything else I can do?

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*?

Comment: Actually, having checked, my string "parts" equals something ridiculous like [Ljava.lang.String;@db2e44d.

Comment: Ok-- what do I want to do instead of if (parts.equals(morse[x])) ? I'm at a loss here.

Comment: I tried your suggestion (it's definitely right) but it's still a no go. Is something wrong with the split? I read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You might be meaning `continue` and not `break`

- `continue` starts the next iteration of the outer loop
- `break` jumps out of the loop and executes the first line of code after the for loop ends.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that part's fine. Thanks, though!

Comment: Fair enough, have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: I'll be honest, I have absolutely no idea how to.

Comment: Have a Google for it, it'll be one of the most useful things you can learn.